Tails not booting using USB - stuck at systemd-journald.service/start
I downloaded the official tails 6.6 image file here. And followed all the steps mentioned and made my bootable usb drive.
But when I booted it on my laptop it did not boot for hours. I checked the log by pressing Escape and saw this in the console -
I 134.00170 systemd[1]: modprobe@dm_mod,service: Deactivated successfully. I l34.004731 systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@dm.mod.service - Load Kernel Module dm_mod► t ","N I Finished modprobe@dm.mod.service - Load Kernel Module dm_mod. I 1 .013,S21 systemd[1]: modprobeOefi_pstore.service: Deactivated successfully. I 134.0141111 ,stemd[11: Finished modprobellefi_pstore.service - Load Kernel Module efi.pstore► t I Finished modprobeeefi_pstore.service - Load Kernel Module efi_pstore. [ 1314.01.5.66$1 systemd[1]: modprobeeloop.service: Deactivated successfully. t 134.416171] systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@loop.service - Load Kernel Module loop. t Q I Finished modprobOloop.service - Load Kernel Module loop. t 134.0184831 systemdt11: systemd-pstore.service - Platform Persistent Storage Archival was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionDirectoryNotEmoty./sys/fs/pstore). t 134.018M systemd[1]: systemd-repart.service - Repartition Root Disk was skipped because no trigger condition checks were met. t 134.1782451 systemd[1]: Finished ferm.service - ferm firewall configuration. [ OK I Finished ferm.service - ferm firewall configuration. t 134.1796611 skistemdfl]: Reached target network-pre.target - Preparation for Network. I _ I Reached target network-pre.terget - Preparation for Network. 134.236501] systemd[1]: Starting networking.service - Raise network interfaces... Starting networking.service - Raise network interfaces-t 134.3795861 sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0 134.526498] systemd[1]: Finished networking.service - Raise network interfaces. [ OK I Finished networking.service - Raise network interfaces. I Job systemd-journald.service/start running (1min 26s / 1min 26s) ] Job systemd-journald.service/start running (1min 31s / lmin 31s) [ 226.102265] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing. [ **,] Job sastemd-journald.service/start running (lmin 37s / 1min 37s) [ .1,] Job systemd-journald.service/start running (1min 42s / 1min 42s) [ 236.602216] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: State 'final-sigterm' timed out. Killing. I , ] Job systemd-journald.service/start running (lmin 47s / 1min 47s) [ 241.852215] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Processes still around after final SIGKILL. Entering failed mode. [ 241.854586] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Failed with result 'timeout'. [ 241.858583] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Unit process 646 (systemd-journal) remains running after unit stopped. [FAILED] Failed to start systemd-journald.service - Journal Service. See 'systemctl status systemd-journald.service' for details. [ 241.865415] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1. [ 241.866111] systemd[1]: Stopped systemd-journald.service - Journal Service. [ OK ] Stopped systemd-journald.service - Journal Service. [ 241.867922] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Found left-over process 646 (systemd-journal) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring. [ 241.867927] systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies. [ 241.905246] systemd[1]: Starting systemd-journald.service - Journal Service... Starting systemd-journald.service - Journal Service... [ 241. 29] systemd-journald[4031]: File /run/log/Journal/Bafbee1b601542bb908b095e9aef3d91/system.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing. [ ] Job systemd-journald.service/start running (1min 11s / lain 30s) [ 332.102488] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: start operation timed out. Terminating. [ 337.352241] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: State 'stop-sigterpe timed out. Killing. [ 337.354842] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Killing process 11 (systemd-journal) with signal SIGKILL. [ ] Job systemd-journald.service/start running (lmin 40s / imin Os) [ ] Job systemd-journald.service/start running (lmin 45s / lmin 45s) [ 347.852233] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: State 'final-sigterm' timed out. Killing. [ 347.855173] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Killing process 4031 (systemd-journal) with signal SIGKILL. [ ] Job systemd-journald.service/start running (lmin 50s / imin 50s) [ 353.1019721 systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Processes still around after final SIGKILL. Entering failed mode. [ 353.104411] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Failed with result 'timeout'. [ 353.107123] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Unit process 646 (systemd-journal) remains running after unit stopped. [ 353.: .1 systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Unit process 4031 (systemd-journal) remains running after unit stopped. [FAILED] hailed to start systemd-journald.service - Journal Service. See 'systemctl status systemd-journald.service' for details. [ 353.116852] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2. [ 353.117378] systemd[1]: Stopped systemd-journald.service - Journal Service. ] Stopped systemd-journald.service - Journal Service. [ 353.124921] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Found left-over process 646 (systemd-journal) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring. [ 353.124934] systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies. [ 353.125005] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Found left-over process 4031 (systemd-journal) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring. [ 353.125017] systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies. 353. 1 systemd[1]: Starting systemd-journald.service - Journal Service... Starting systemd-journald.service - Journal Service... 353.167892] systemd-journald[4035]: File /run/log/journalaafbee1b601542bb908b095e9aef3d91/system.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing. 1 Job systemd-journald.service/start running (29s / lmin 30s) 
Basically it is stuck in exiting and then retrying to start the systemd-journald.service.
I tried different usb slot and drives with no success.
When I tried to boot in a different laptop I was greeted with Verifying shim SBAT data failed: Security Policy Violation Something has gone seriosuly wrong: SBAT self-check failed: Security Policy Violation
I have tried enabling and disabling secure boot and fast startup.
I am only booting Windows 11. And my device is Asus ROG Zephyrus G14 2021.
Thank You

Gaming PCs (or laptops) with Nvidia graphics are NOT recommended to use with Tails. Use Tails only with Intel or AMD graphics because their drivers are open-source and already included in the kernel. Old Nvidia cards should work fine because they have acceptable support with the community alternative driver nouveau.

But it's not booting, how can I figure out if that is the problem. Also I own only one device at hand. Even if that is the problem, is there an alternative. Btw my device has GTX 1650 so fairly old, don't know about support for it.

Tails' kernels lag beyond mainstream distros by a lot. So, for Tails, GTX1650 is pretty new. And even today, most of the times we have to use the "safe graphics" mode (or nomodeset) to run alive session with that card. It works perfectly once the Nvidia proprietary drivers are installed and running, something that'll never happen in Tails. Tails has a very specific purpose and definitely NOT to be used with hardware such as yours. If you have the option to select the iGPU instead in UEFI you may have a chance to boot Tails.

Furthermore, your USB drive may have errors, the copying process may have failed, the ISO file itself can be corrupt, etc. etc. It's up to you to troubleshoot this by doing the logic and quite obvious steps.

But it's not booting It is obviously booting otherwise you wouldn't have the huge log you posted for no good reason. The problem is it stopping right before the graphical environment is supposed to load.

Sorry, for the late reply, I was caught up in something else and forgot about this question.
I have used two USB, so maybe it might be a coincidence that the USB are corrupt, but I did multiple downloads and verified the signatures too. Also tried another distro (Parrot OS) and it ran. I will try your solution of using the iGPU, and revert back.

I have the same issue with Tails 6.6 on the same model of Zephyrus G14, the issue is something to do with the 6.6 release version of Tails, as booting on 6.5 works completely fine for me, nomodeset isn't even required. Also, the issue is not necessarily caused by drivers lagging behind. A case of kernel's lagging behind or completely missing drivers, is something like Kali Linux, which requires the nomodeset boot argument to be able to boot on our laptops, after which you could install proper drivers and remove that boot argument.
However Tails 6.5 still has the standard issues on Asus/dual GPU laptops, i.e. the OS generally being really slow, persistent storage not working (for me personally, with multiple different USBs, not sure if this is a general issue or just my setup) and having the dGPU constantly running, thus really heating up the laptop and eating through the battery. It's still fine for using Tor over shorter periods of time, but in the case that you want something else from Linux, I recommend using Fedora (works well on my Zephyrus G14), and since you seem fairly new to Linux, I STRONGLY recommend you to check out Asus-Linux.org, they have some useful guides, especially for setting up proper hardware integration on our laptops. Additionally, secure boot should be disabled, and fast startup shouldn't matter.
You can download archived versions of Tails from DistroWatch, or alternatively, you can build different versions from the source, since release versions are tagged on the Tails GitLab.

Thanks for the solution. I will try it. I never looked for the older version, because I thought it's all basis of security so older versions would have some bug. Thus, I only tried to install the latest version.
Also I did know about the Asus-Linux but I did not use the guides cause there was very limited number of guides for the distro and I did not want to checkout Arch or Fedora at the moment.
Also sorry, for the late reply, I was caught up in something else and forgot about this question.
